# How to Encrypt app.config for multiple users using aspnet_regiis exe?

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, app-config

I am working on windows application where I want to encrypt app.config file for multiple users.
I am following steps mentioned on document [here](https://github.com/jcefoli/.NETConfigSectionEncryption)

As step, If I want to grand permission to user, I will execute below command

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pa MyContainer "DOMAIN\svc_MyApp"
```

When I export this file and import in other machine, if I login with same user who has permission, it works fine. But if I login with different user, it wont work which is expected behavior.

My questions is- How can I grand permission to multiple users for the file?
As per [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#configuration-options) -We can grand permission to user group.

```
-pa container account

Grants permission for the specified user or group account to access the specified key container.
```

But we dont want to create group for app users.

How can I give permission to multiple users to decrypt the file and so read configuration?